# Python variables as keys to dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there an easier way to do this in Python (2.7)?: Note: This isn't anything fancy, like putting all local variables into a dictionary. Just the ones I specify in a list.

```
apple = 1
banana = 'f'
carrot = 3
fruitdict = {}

# I want to set the key equal to variable name, and value equal to variable value
# is there a more Pythonic way to get {'apple': 1, 'banana': 'f', 'carrot': 3}?

for x in [apple, banana, carrot]:
    fruitdict[x] = x # (Won't work)
```

Comment: Can the variables be defined in the dict?  Like fruitdict = dict(apple=1, banana=2, carrot=3) ?

Comment: Not really, there's a lot of code for each variable so it'd be unreadable.

Comment: I assume you're aware that you code doesn't do what you the comment says it does?  You can't go backwards from objects to names unless you find what you want in a namespace dictionary like locals()  You could however write a function that looks up these variables in the namespace dictionary and assigns the values found to that key; see jimbob's answer.

Comment: Yep, sorry, I should clarify.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

```
for i in ('apple', 'banana', 'carrot'):
    fruitdict[i] = locals()[i]
```

Comment: one-line ``dict([(i, locals()[i]) for i in ('apple', 'banana', 'carrot')])``

Comment: While this question is about 2.7, note that the above one-liner does not work in Python 3 because `locals()` apparently points to the scope of the list comprehension.

Comment: So what's the solution in Python 3?

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś you set `loc=locals()` before `dict([(i, loc[i]) for in ('apple', 'banana', 'carrot')])`.

Comment: `{i: loc[i] for i in ('apple', 'banana', 'carrot')}`, no need to create a list and convert it to a dict.

Answer (score 24):

The [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#globals) function returns a dictionary containing all your global variables.

```
>>> apple = 1
>>> banana = 'f'
>>> carrot = 3
>>> globals()
{'carrot': 3, 'apple': 1, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, 'banana': 'f'}
```

There is also a similar function called [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals).

I realise this is probably not exactly what you want, but it may provide some insight into how Python provides access to your variables.

**Edit**: It sounds like your problem may be better solved by simply using a dictionary in the first place:

```
fruitdict = {}
fruitdict['apple'] = 1
fruitdict['banana'] = 'f'
fruitdict['carrot'] = 3
```

Comment: Sorry, I must have edited after you were writing your answer. I only need the variables I specify, not all locals() or globals()

Comment: @Jasie: I added an example of simply using a dictionary in the first place, instead of messing around with variables.

Answer (score 11):

A one-liner is:-

```
fruitdict = dict(zip(('apple','banana','carrot'), (1,'f', '3'))
```

Comment: Thanks, but the numbers were random assignments (didn't need a range()).

Answer (score 3):

Here it is in one line, without having to retype any of the variables or their values:

```
fruitdict.update({k:v for k,v in locals().copy().iteritems() if k[:2] != '__' and k != 'fruitdict'})
```

Answer (score 2):

Well this is a bit, umm ... non-Pythonic ... ugly ... hackish ...

Here's a snippet of code assuming you want to create a dictionary of all the local variables you
create after a specific checkpoint is taken:

```
checkpoint = [ 'checkpoint' ] + locals().keys()[:]
## Various local assigments here ...
var_keys_since_checkpoint = set(locals().keys()) - set(checkpoint)
new_vars = dict()
for each in var_keys_since_checkpoint:
   new_vars[each] = locals()[each]
```

Note that we explicitly add the 'checkpoint' key into our capture of the `locals().keys()`  I'm also explicitly taking a slice of that though it shouldn't be necessary in this case since the reference has to be flattened to add it to the [ 'checkpoint' ] list.  However, if you were using a variant of this code and tried to shortcut out the `['checkpoint'] + portion (because that key was already in`locals()`, for example) ... then, without the [:] slice you could end up with a reference to the`locals().keys()` whose values would change as you added variables.

Offhand I can't think of a way to call something like `new_vars.update()` with a list of keys to be added/updated.  So the`for` loop is most portable.  I suppose a dictionary comprehension could be used in more recent versions of Python.  However that woudl seem to be nothing more than a round of code golf.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer by mouad, here's a more pythonic way to select the variables based on a prefix:

```
# All the vars that I want to get start with fruit_
fruit_apple = 1
fruit_carrot = 'f'
rotten = 666

prefix = 'fruit_'
sourcedict = locals()
fruitdict = { v[len(prefix):] : sourcedict[v]
              for v in sourcedict
              if v.startswith(prefix) }
# fruitdict = {'carrot': 'f', 'apple': 1}
```

You can even put that in a function with prefix and sourcedict as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest version might be:

```py
fruit_dict = dict(apple=apple, banana=banana, carrot=carrot)
```

Answer (score -1):

This question has practically been answered, but I just wanted to say it was funny that you said

> This isn't anything fancy, like
>   putting all local variables into a
>   dictionary.

Because it is actually "fancier"

what you want is:

```
apple = 1
banana = 'f'
carrot = 3
fruitdict = {}

# I want to set the key equal to variable name, and value equal to variable value
# is there a more Pythonic way to get {'apple': 1, 'banana': 'f', 'carrot': 3}?

names= 'apple banana carrot'.split() # I'm just being lazy for this post
items = globals()                    # or locals()

for name in names:
    fruitdict[name] = items[name]
```

Honestly, what you are doing is just copying items from one dictionary to another.

(Greg Hewgill practically gave the whole answer, I just made it complete)

...and like people suggested, you should probably be putting these in the dictionary in the first place, but I'll assume that for some reason you can't

Comment: so I guess I didn't see jimbob's post... practically the same thing, just doesn't call locals/globals more than once

Comment: I'm don't think calling globals more than once would actually be more efficient.

Comment: E.g., if you do items = locals(); id(locals()) == id(items) you would get equality.  Or if you did items=locals(); b = 3 ; items['b'] it will find the new variable b, since it didn't actually copy the locals dict to items (which would be slower).  If you had done items=locals().copy() there may have been a minor difference; but then again the copying step is probably slower than accessing the small number of items from the locals dict.

Answer (score -2):

Not the most elegant solution, and only works 90% of the time:

```
def vardict(*args):
    ns = inspect.stack()[1][0].f_locals
    retval = {}
    for a in args:
        found = False
        for k, v in ns.items():
            if a is v:
                retval[k] = v
                if found:
                    raise ValueError("Value found in more than one local variable: " + str(a))
                found = True
        if found:
            continue
        if 'self' in ns:
            for k, v in ns['self'].__dict__.items():
                if a is v:
                    retval[k] = v
                    if found:
                        raise ValueError("Value found in more than one instance attribute: " + str(a))
                    found = True
        if found:
            continue
        for k, v in globals().items():
            if a is v:
                retval[k] = v
                if found:
                    raise ValueError("Value found in more than one global variable: " + str(a))
                found = True
        assert found, "Couldn't find one of the parameters."
    return retval
```

You'll run into problems if you store the same reference in multiple variables, but also if multiple variables store the same small int, since these get interned.

Answer (score -3):

why you don't do the opposite :

```
fruitdict = { 
      'apple':1,
      'banana':'f',
      'carrot':3,
}

locals().update(fruitdict)
```

**Update :**

don't use the code above check the comment.

by the way why you don't mark the vars that you want to get i don't know 
maybe like this:

```
# All the vars that i want to get are followed by _fruit
apple_fruit = 1
carrot_fruit = 'f'

for var in locals():
    if var.endswith('fruit'):
       you_dict.update({var:locals()[var])
```

Comment: Updating `locals()` like that is truly evil.

Comment: As a friend of mine says: 'dark voodoo'

Comment: agree, but my understanding of his question is that he want to get only variable that are __fruit and legume__ ; which is basically impossible unless he could teach his program to make difference between __fruit and legume__ and other stuff , or maybe i just complicate thing maybe he just want "carrot , banana , apple" vars :)

Comment: updating locals() is **forbidden**  http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
to_dict = lambda **k: k
apple = 1
banana = 'f'
carrot = 3
to_dict(apple=apple, banana=banana, carrot=carrot)
#{'apple': 1, 'banana': 'f', 'carrot': 3}
```

Comment: How is different from simply doing `dict(apple=apple, banana=banana, carrot=carrot)`?

Answer (score -5):

```
a = "something"
randround = {}
randround['A'] = "%s" % a
```

Worked.

Comment: It should be `{'a' : 'something'}` and you are getting `{'A' : 'something'}`... you are hard coding the Key `A`