# Does Python support object literal property value shorthand, a la ECMAScript 6?

Tags: javascript, python, dictionary, ecmascript-6

In ECMAScript 6, I can do something like this ...

```
var id = 1;
var name = 'John Doe';
var email = 'email@example.com';
var record = { id, name, email };
```

... as a shorthand for this:

```
var id = 1;
var name = 'John Doe';
var email = 'email@example.com';
var record = { 'id': id, 'name': name, 'email': email };
```

Is there any similar feature in Python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python variables as keys to dict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972872/python-variables-as-keys-to-dict)

Comment: Nop, `{ id, name, email }` is a set-literal in Python.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, but you can achieve identical thing doing this

```
record = {i: locals()[i] for i in ('id', 'name', 'email')}
```

(credits to [Python variables as keys to dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972872/python-variables-as-keys-to-dict))

Your example, typed in directly in python is same as set and is not a dictionary

```
{id, name, email} == set((id, name, email))
```

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no similar shorthand in Python. It would even introduce an ambiguity with `set` literals, which have that exact syntax:

```
>>> foo = 'foo'
>>> bar = 'bar'
>>> {foo, bar}
set(['foo', 'bar'])
>>> {'foo': foo, 'bar': bar}
{'foo': 'foo', 'bar': 'bar'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't easily use object literal shorthand because of set literals, and `locals()` is a little unsafe.

I wrote a [hacky gist](https://gist.github.com/AlexeyMK/6084626) a couple of years back that creates a `d` function that you can use, a la

```
record = d(id, name, email, other=stuff)
```

Going to see if I can package it a bit more nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get this quite nicely with a dark magic library called [sorcery](https://github.com/alexmojaki/sorcery) which offers `dict_of`:

```py
x = dict_of(foo, bar)
# same as:
y = {"foo": foo, "bar": bar}
```

Note that you can also unpack like ES6:

```py
foo, bar = unpack_keys(x)
# same as:
foo = x['foo']
bar = x['bar']
```

This may be confusing to experienced Pythonistas, and is probably not a wise choice for performance-sensitive codepaths.