# storing python variable and its value as dictionary in robotframework

Tags: python, robotframework

I have python file, which is mandatory to be used as variable file i.e. -V

content of file is

```
Volte_user_01='samsung'
Volte_user_02='HTC'
cs_test='Vivo'
```

I am trying to find a way by which I can store all the variables having **'user'**  text in variable name  in a dictionary in robot framework.

so the dictionary in robotframe work would be like

```
${Phones} = {Volte_user_01:'samsung', Volte_user_02: 'HTC'}
```

I went through the documentation , but its bit complex to understand

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You cannot call a key variable in a dictionary ([how it's done here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972872/python-variables-as-keys-to-dict)). Keys with the same names are not available in the default Python dictionaries.

Comment: That was a typo..corrected now

Comment: Is there a reason you don't do this in the variable file itself?

Comment: You would probably want to store those variables in config files and pass them as parameters to your python objects when you run the test. The ${..} syntax is normally only used for runtime variables inside a robot testcase.

Comment: @BryanOakley it's a requirement, parameters needs to be passed as scalar data type from python file

Comment: I don't understand why you can't pass both the scalars, and a dictionary that has the data you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect there are better ways to solve the problem you're trying to solve, but here's a literal answer to your question.

Robot has a keyword named [get variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Get%20Variables) which returns a dictionary of all known robot variables. Robot also has a keyword named [evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) which lets you run arbitrary python code. In that code, you can reference robot variables by using the special syntax `$varname`.

Using those keywords, you can create a dictionary comprehension that creates a new dictionary for you.

In the following example, and using the data from your original question, the keyword `Get user variables` will return a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{
    'Volte_user_1': samsung, 
    'Volte_user_02': HTC
}
```

Note that if you have other variables that have the string "*user*" in their name, they will show up in the list too.

```
*** Keywords ***
Get user variables
    [Documentation] 
    ...  Return a dictionary of key/value pairs where the keys
    ...  are all robot variables that have _user_ as part of 
    ...  their name. 
    ${vars}=  get variables
    ${user variables}=  evaluate
    ...  {name[2:-1]:value for (name,value) in $vars.items() if "_user_" in name}
    [Return]  ${user variables}    

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    ${phones}=  get user variables
    should be equal  ${phones['Volte_user_01']}  samsung
    should be equal  ${phones['Volte_user_02']}  HTC
```