# Creating a dictionary with variable as key

Tags: python-3.x

The following gives KeyErrors:

```
from datetime import datetime

a = "Some Text"
d = datetime.now()

def create_dict(*args):
   dict([(i, locals()[i]) for i in args])

create_dict(a, d)
```

instead of:
{'a': 'Some Text', 'd': 04-06-2018}

Where is it going wrong?

Comment: have you checked the value of `d`? is it valid? Maybe you imported just `datetime` and not `datetime.datetime` so it would be  `d = datetime.datetime.now()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python variables as keys to dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972872/python-variables-as-keys-to-dict)

Comment: The value of d is correct. How can dictionary be created using variables declared outside the function, with variable names as the keys?

Comment: @reservoirinvest if you need to use the variables defined outside the function (global scope) inside the function (local scope) you need to define `global variable_name` inside the function as well and then you can use the variable

Comment: @iam sample code will be helpful.

Comment: @reservoirinvest I've posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

A nifty dictionary comprehension can be used.

To get all global scoped variables, you can simply do the below:

```
global_var = {key: globals()[key] for i in args for key in globals().keys() if i == globals()[key]}
```

To get all the local scoped variables, you can simply to the below:

```
local_var = {key: locals()[key] for i in args for key in locals().keys() if i == locals()[key]}
```

> If you're using them together, make sure you add them in a single `dict` so that you avoid modifying the collection on which you're iterating

If you wana learn more about scopes in python [refer to this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/)