# ES6-like object shorthand for Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, ecmascript-6, shorthand

For API interaction, I need to 'summarize' some variables in a dictionary. A basic approach would be like

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

d = {
    'a': a,
    'b': b,
    'c': c,
}
```

which seems to be somehow repetitive, especially for 15+ variables.

To reduce optical clutter and repetition, I wondered whether Python does have something like [ES6's object shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015) which allows to do:

```
const a = 1;
const b = 2;
const c = 3;

const obj = {
    a,
    b,
    c
}
```

I found an [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3972978/3991125), but accessing the variables via the [`locals()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) seems to be a somehow ugly workaround.

Does Python support an ES6-comparable shorthand notation to create a dictionary from variables?

Comment: I'm not aware of any other way to get variables names as strings without using `locals()` or something analogous. What would be "comparable" for you, concretely speaking?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "comparable". Does passing keyword args like `dict(a=a, b=b, c=c)` sound comparable? (IMO no because it's as repetitive as your current approach anyway)

Comment: Why do you need `a`, `b`, etc as local variables in the first place when you're already declaring them in the dictionary?  If you did want to make a dict that copies all the variables in the local scope you could just do `d = locals().copy()`, but even if you're not duplicating the code you're still duplicating the state for no particularly good reason.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for doesn't exist in Python.

Answer (score -1):

This ought to lessen typing. The key is to the `dict` constructor rather than the literal declaration syntax `{}`

```
#can also use outside vars
d = 4

obj = dict(
a = 1,
b = 2,
c = 3,
d = d,
)
```

Comment: What they're asking for is a syntax to have the keys and values be the same, as if you're writing an array. This is not a shorthand syntax that they have asked for, as you still type the key and value.

Comment: @ProblemsLoop.  You don’t say?  Really?  Wow, I never knew.   That’s about as short as Python makes the dict literal, sorry.  Minus quotes is about all.  But it’s that and no need to explain to me what they wanted.